# Akka http: how to make complete function see my Encoders?

Tags: scala, marshalling, akka-http

I have a couple of case classes and made encoders for them

```
trait appJSONProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val jsCat = jsonFormat4(Category)
  implicit val jsCatRel = jsonFormat3(CategoryRel)

  implicit val encodeCat: Encoder[Category] =
    Encoder.forProduct4("id", "name", "parentId", "level")(u =>
      (u.id, u.name, u.parentId, u.level)
    )

  implicit val encodeCatRel: Encoder[CategoryRel] =
    Encoder.forProduct6("id", "name", "parentId", "level", "parentOfMine", "children")(u =>
      (u.category.id, u.category.name, u.category.parentId, u.category.level, u.parent, u.children)
    )
}
```

now i want to make response according these encoders

```
def completeTask[T] (task: Future[T])(
    implicit encoder: Encoder[T],
    m: ToEntityMarshaller[T]
  ) = {
    onComplete(task) {
      case Success(data) => {
        println(data.asJson)
        complete(OK, data)
      }
      case Failure(throwable) =>
        complete(BadRequest, throwable.getMessage)
    }
  }
```

data.asJson works perfectly well, but complete function returns json as it does not see my encoders. It seems like it expects some EntityMarshaller parameter, but how and where can i apply Encoder then?

Comment: complete, the RouteDirective returns a Route not a json. The encoder is applied putting in scope the json serializer and importing the SprayJson support.

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44, Yes, i ment the result in browser not returning value itself... SprayJsonSupport is in scope, what is "json serializer"?

Comment: serializer, encoder, marshaller... the module that takes your type and converts to a JSON string

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44, strange, it all is in scope, inside `object ScalaIshopCats extends App with appJSONProtocol with SprayJsonSupport``, so appJSONProtocol  contains encoders

Answer (score 0):

Finally this implicit function helped to translate my encoders to ToEntityMarshaller type

```
implicit final def marshaller[A: Encoder]: ToEntityMarshaller[A] = {
    Marshaller.withFixedContentType(`application/json`) { a =>
      HttpEntity(`application/json`, a.asJson.noSpaces)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

While your solution works, there's not really a reason to write this yourself. There's an implementation in a library:

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/json-support.html#spray-json-support

Mix in the
`akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport` trait and you're done.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, if i remove the code in my solution above and add inherit SprayJsonSupport i again get an error "could not find implicit value for parameter m: akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.ToEntityMarshaller[T]
      case Success(data) => complete(OK, data)"

Comment: There's something wrong with your code. There is no `Encoder` type in spray-json, which means you're apparently mixing two different JSON libraries here - probably spray-json (which contains `DefaultJsonProtocol`) and circe (which provides `Encoder`). So you need to make up your mind about which one you want to use and then add the relevant Akka HTTP support library. For circe, that is https://github.com/hseeberger/akka-http-json .